# Cannot set menu name

Tags: codeigniter

I am having difficult to display menu with this code. In the parent menu i just get 'Array' displayed instead of menu name. Here is the code.

model

```
function getCategoriesNav(){
    //page 157

    $data = array();
    $this->db->select('id, name, parentid');
    $this->db->where('status', 'active');
    $this->db->order_by('parentid', 'asc');
    $this->db->order_by('name', 'asc');
    $this->db->group_by('parentid', 'id');
    $Q = $this->db->get('categories');
    if($Q->num_rows >0){
        foreach($Q->result() as $row){
            if($row->parentid > 0){
                $data[0][$row->parentid]['children'][$row->id] = $row->name;
            }else{
            $data[0][$row->id]['name'] = $row->name;
            }
        }
    }
    $Q->free_result();
    return $data;
}
```

controller is

```
function index()
{
    $data['title'] = 'News';
    $data['navlist'] = $this->MCats->getCategoriesNav();
    $data['mainf'] = $this->MProducts->getMainFeature();
    $skip = $data['mainf']['id'];
    $data['sidef'] = $this->MProducts->getRandomProducts(3, $skip);
    $data['main'] = 'home';
    $this->load->vars($data);
    $this->load->view('template');
}
```

and the view is

```
<?php

if(count($navlist)){
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($navlist as $key => $list){
            foreach($list as $topkey => $toplist){
                echo "<li class='cat'>";
                echo anchor("welcome/cat/$topkey", $toplist);
                echo "</li>\n";
                    if(count($toplist['children'])){
                        foreach($toplist['children'] as $subkey => $subname){
                            echo "\n<li class='subcat'>";
                            echo anchor("welcome/cat/$subkey", $subname);
                            echo "</li>";
                }
            }
        }

    }
    echo "</ul>\n";

}


?>
```

please help

Comment: `print_r($data['navList']);` does that return expected results?

Comment: no it doesn't return expected result, pls help

Comment: it's giving Array
(
    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => animal
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [11] => cats
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [3] => jeans
                )

        )

[name] is not showing on the second array and there are more than one children, it's showing only one children pls help

Comment: I tried to address your missing elements in an edit to my answer.  Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is my examination of your array structure:

You have a four level multi-dimensional array to hold a row name.

[0][parent id]['children'][row id] = row name.

Your `foreach(navlist as key=>list)` sets up [parent id] as `$key` and ['children'][row id] = row name as `$list`.

Your `foreach($list as $topkey=>$toplist)` sets up ['children'] as `$topkey` and [row id] = row name as `$toplist`.

Your call to `anchor('welcome/cat/$topkey, $toplist)` is sending an array to the anchor helper function, which may be why you are seeing 'array' output to the browser.  This function only accepts a string for the 'text to display' argument.

**EDIT**

To answer your comment, try this in your view:

Instead of:

```
echo anchor("welcome/cat/$topkey", $toplist);
```

Use this:

```
echo anchor("welcome/cat/$topkey", $toplist['name']);
```

Now you will be passing the value of `$data[0][$row->id]['name']` which is your construct to hold `$row->name` in your model.

EDIT 2:

I also notice your use of

```
if($Q->num_rows >0){
```

You are missing the parenthesis for the num_rows function.

```
if($Q->num_rows() > 0) {
```

This may have something to do with your missing parent and children categories.  If not, I recommend removing your `group_by()` clause from the query, just to see if that is messing things up for you.  If those don't help, keep remove the `order_by()`'s and see what happens.

Comment: what should i do to get menu name ?

Comment: @sagamatha, I edited my answer to address your comment question